# What is the correct way to mix feature sparse matrices with sklearn?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, scikit-learn

The other day I was dealing with a machine learning task that required to extract several types of feature matrices. I save this feature matrices as numpy arrays in disk in order to later use them in some estimator (this was a classification task). After all, when I wanted to use all the features I just concatenated the matrices in order to have a big feature matrix. When I obtained this big feature matrix I presented it to an estimator.

I do not know if this is the correct way to work with a feature matrix that has a lot of patterns (counts) in it. **What other approaches should I use to mix correctly several types of features?**. However, looking through the documentation I found [FeatureUnion](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.FeatureUnion.html#sklearn.pipeline.FeatureUnion) that seems to do this task.

For example, Let's say I would like to create a big feature matrix of 3 vectorizer approaches `TfidfVectorizer`, `CountVectorizer` and `HashingVectorizer` This is what I tried following the [documentation example](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/auto_examples/feature_stacker.html#example-feature-stacker-py):

```
#Read the .csv file
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv',
                     header=0, sep=',', names=['id', 'text', 'labels'])

#vectorizer 1
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
tfidf_vect = TfidfVectorizer(use_idf=True, smooth_idf=True,
                             sublinear_tf=False, ngram_range=(2,2))
#vectorizer 2
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
bow = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(2,2))

#vectorizer 3
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import HashingVectorizer
hash_vect = HashingVectorizer(ngram_range=(2,2))


#Combine the above vectorizers in one single feature matrix:

from sklearn.pipeline import  FeatureUnion
combined_features = FeatureUnion([("tfidf_vect", tfidf_vect),
                                  ("bow", bow),
                                  ("hash",hash_vect)])

X_combined_features = combined_features.fit_transform(df['text'].values)
y = df['labels'].values

#Check the matrix
print X_combined_features.toarray()
```

Then:

```
[[ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 ..., 
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]]
```

Split the data:

```
from sklearn import cross_validation
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = cross_validation.train_test_split(X_combined_features,y, test_size=0.33)
```

So I have a few questions: 
**Is this the right approach to mix several feature extractors in order to yield a big feature matrix?** and **assume I create my own "vectorizers" and they return sparse matrices, how can I use correctly the FeatureUnion interface to mix them with the above 3 features?**.

**update**

Let's say that I have a matrix like this:

Matrix A (`(152, 33)`)

```
[[ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 ..., 
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]]
```

Then with my vectorizer that returns a [numpy array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.asarray.html) I get this feature matrix:

Matrix B (`(152, 10)`)

```
[[4210  228   25 ...,    0    0    0]
 [4490  180   96 ...,   10    4    6]
 [4795  139    8 ...,    0    0    1]
 ..., 
 [1475   58    3 ...,    0    0    0]
 [4668  256   25 ...,    0    0    0]
 [1955  111   10 ...,    0    0    0]]
```

Matrix C (`(152, 46)`)

```
[[ 0  0  0 ...,  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0 ...,  0  0 17]
 [ 0  0  0 ...,  0  0  0]
 ..., 
 [ 0  0  0 ...,  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0 ...,  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0 ...,  0  0  0]]
```

How can I merge A, B and C correctly with `numpy.hstack`,`scipy.sparse.hstack` or `FeatureUnion`? . Do you guys think this is a correct pipeline-approach to follow for any machine learning task?

Answer (score 6):

> Is this the right approach to mix several feature extractors in order to yield a big feature matrix?

In terms of correctness of the result, your approach is right, since `FeatureUnion` runs each individual transformer on the input data and concatenates the resulting matrices horizontally. However, it's not the only way, and which way is better in terms of efficiency will depend on your use case (more on this later).

> Assume I create my own "vectorizers" and they return sparse matrices, how can I use correctly the FeatureUnion interface to mix them with the above 3 features?

Using `FeatureUnion`, you simply need to append your new transformer to the transformer list:

```
custom_vect = YourCustomVectorizer()
combined_features = FeatureUnion([("tfidf_vect", tfidf_vect),
                                  ("bow", bow),
                                  ("hash", hash_vect),
                                  ("custom", custom_vect])
```

However, if your input data and most of the transformers are fixed (e.g. when you're experimenting with the inclusion of a new transformer), the above approach will lead to many re-computation. In that case, an alternative approach is to pre-compute store the intermediate results of the transformers (matrices or sparse matrices), and concatenate them manually using `numpy.hstack` or `scipy.sparse.hstack` when needed.

If your input data is always changing but the list of transformers is fixed, `FeatureUnion` offers more convenience. Another advantage of it is that it has the option of `n_jobs`, which helps you parallelize the fitting process.

---

Side note: It seems little bit strange to mix hashing vectorizer with the other vectorizers, since hashing vectorizer is typically used when you cannot afford to use the exact versions.

Comment: Thanks for the help. One thing to comes to my mind is what about the dimesions?. How can I merge the matrices taking care about the dimensions?.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what you mean by "taking care" of the dimensions? Using the appropriate stacking function in numpy/scipy, the merged dimension (X.shape[1]) is the sum of the dimension of the individual feature matrices.

Comment: Thanks for the support, I edited the question with an example.

Comment: I think you have to choose between ``FeatureUnion`` and ``hstack``. Essentially, the ``hstack`` approach is the same as you doing the job of ``FeatureUnion`` manually. Choose either *one* of them, but not both.

Comment: Finally, could you provide an example in order to have a better idea of this issue?. Thanks for the help!